# Redshift transformation: json key/value to relation

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

in the Redshift table I have the `tag` column, which is varchar storing `json` with typical key/value pairs. E.g. for record with id = 1 the `tag` value looks like:  `{"env":"test","app-name":"ap123","product-type":"web-app"}`.

I would like to transform the key/values to the typical relational table like below:

```
+---+-------------+-------+
|id ||key         |value  |
+---+-------------+-------+
|1  |env          |test   |
|1  |app-name     |ap123  |
|1  |product-type |web-app|
|2  |env          |dev    |
|...|...          |...    |
+---+-------------+-------+
```

I had made a fast research already I didn't found any solution. I tried to use the Redshift json functions, but without achieving the desired result (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html).

Any ideas are highly wellcome.

Comment: Please elaborate on what "Redshift json functions" you have used and what the result was so that people don't waste time suggesting solutions that you have already tried.

Comment: I tested e.g. JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY _ELEMENT _TEXT and JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea in this situation was to change the json to json_array by adding enclosing brackets ('[' and ']') to the json and replace ',' with the '}, {' to change separate json_array elements. Afther that it's possible to access the json_array element by the json_extract_array_element_text function.